# Time based javascript, creating a blank response for approx 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, time

First - thanks in advance for your help. 
I have a image based slide show, that calls #photo1, 2, 3.  Using javascript to change the image (actually the image folder, all images have the same name, so just changing root folder) based on various time blocks throughout the day. (9am-11am, 11am-3pm, 3-6pm, 6pm-9am). In case it matters, I am storing the images on dropbox (so my buddy can change them at will, the links provided are old and not currently working).
It all seems to be working, accept for approx the first 30 minutes after the change time, it goes blank. Then works fine again. 
Thoughts? I am not great with javascript, so if I am going about this all wrong, I am open to new approaches.

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

  // If time is after 9AM or before 11AM
if (n > 9 && n < 11) {
$("img#photo1").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/324....67l/ad1.jpg?dl=0");
$("img#photo2").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5i9f....m10z/ad2.jpg?dl=0");
$("img#photo3").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n7....66/ad3.jpg?dl=0");
}

else if (n > 11 && n < 15) {
 $("img#photo1").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/31p....rw3r/ad1.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo2").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h3m....tsqy/ad2.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo3").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zr9....kzja/ad3.jpg?dl=0");
 }

else if (n > 15 && n < 18) {
 $("img#photo1").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5li....y2w/ad1.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo2").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/no....twr2/ad2.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo3").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ojjn....i1g/ad3.jpg?dl=0");
 }

else if (n > 18 || n < 9) {
 $("img#photo1").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kn3ch....s7g0/ad1.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo2").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dhxi5....04/ad2.jpg?dl=0");
 $("img#photo3").attr("src","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mb51....336/ad3.jpg?dl=0");
 }

// runs the code every hour, probably there is a much better way to do this 
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();}, 3600000)

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the hour is 9, 11, 15 or 18, none of your conditions will match, and nothing will be displayed.  Change the conditions to:

```
if (n >= 9 && n < 11) {
  // ...
}
else if (n >= 11 && n < 15) {
  // ...
}
else if (n >= 15 && n < 18) {
  // ...
}
else if (n >= 18 || n < 9) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, seems so obvious now looking at it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've excluded 9, 11, 15 and 18; the if statements selects for greater than or less than. You'll get undefined for any of those numbers.